# "That's a relief" = "That's [adjective]"

Tags: single-word-requests

What adjective can be used instead of "a relief" in "That's a relief"?

The only one I can think of is "relieving", but I hope there are better ones.

Comment: It's never *That's relieving!* - in some contexts, *That's **comforting** [to know]* will be "equivalent", but in other contexts it's simply not possible to express exactly the same as *That's a relief!* using an "adjectival" form in English. And there's no reason why the language *should* support such pointless "syntactic shuffling".

Comment: There's lots of words that might do in specific contexts - reassuring, nice, good, positive - but none that will do in every context.

Comment: @user22542 Sorry, can't downvote comments. :)